# Need help to fill arrays

Tags: c

This is the situation: I have written a program that given two arrays `r` and `phi` calculates the coordinates `x,y,z` and prints the on a file i this way:

```
 for(int i=0; i< sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); i++){
            for(int j=0;j< sizeof(phi)/sizeof(phi[0]);j++){
                  z=atan(theta)*r[i]*cos(phi[j]);
                  y=r[i]*sin(phi[j]);
                  x=r[i]*cos(phi[j]);
                  fprintf(file,"%g \t %g \t %g\n", x,y,z)}}
```

Now I need to consider the coordinates as arrays `x[],y[],z[]`, but I cannot find a way to fill the arrays with my current program. The problem is that I cannot find a way to properly iterate on the indices of the coordinates: for example, if I consider the index `i*j` I will get `0` j-times on the first iteration of `i` and so on.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate counter for the resulting arrays and increment it on each iteration of  the inner loop.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i=0; i< sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); i++){
            for(int j=0;j< sizeof(phi)/sizeof(phi[0]);j++){
                  z[k]=atan(theta)*r[i]*cos(phi[j]);
                  y[k]=r[i]*sin(phi[j]);
                  x[k]=r[i]*cos(phi[j]);
                  fprintf(file,"%g \t %g \t %g\n", x[k],y[k],z[k])
                  k++;
             }
}
```